# How do I find the DHCP assigned IP address via bash on Fedora?

Tags: bash, ip, fedora, dhcp

Is there a command within the bash shell of fedora that will give me the currently assigned IP address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ifconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig) is what you're looking for

Comment: ifconfig works as a non-root user. It may not be in your path (/sbin/ifconfig), but you can still run it.

Comment: The output of `ip addr` may be easier to parse.  Like `ifconfig`, it may not be in the default $PATH of a non-root user, but it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
ipconfig getifaddr eth0
```